# How to moq delegate CallBack and lambda method

Tags: c#, .net-core, delegates, moq, xunit

I have Delegate define in C# `SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications` which pass as parameter in the method `ProcessCreateRequestAsync` that trigger the callBack method `SendMessagesAsync`. I am struggling to mock this CallBack function which take `ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification` object.

#### Moq Attempt

```
ringGoApiServiceMoq.Setup(x => x.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(It.IsAny<RingGoExemption>(), It.IsAny<SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(ringGoMessageResponseResultMoq)
        .Callback<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification>(providerExemptionReceivedNotificationMoq);
```

[image]

#### Delegate Definition

```
public delegate Task<bool> SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications(IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions);

public interface IRingGoApiService
{
    Task<RingGoMessageResponseResult> ProcessCreateRequestAsync(RingGoExemption ringGoExemption, SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications sendProviderExemption);
}
```

The following code implements the Delegate;

#### Implementation

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "POST")] HttpRequest req
, [ServiceBus("MyServiceBus", Connection = "MyServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<Message> servicebusMessage
        )
    {
        dynamic responseMessage = null;

        try
        {
            string ringGoTransaction = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ringGoTransaction))
            {
                var ringGoExemption = MapRingGoExemption(ringGoTransaction);

                var result = await _ringGoApiService.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(ringGoExemption,
                    async (IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions) => await SendMessagesAsync(servicebusMessage, exemptions) 
                    ); //This is where I calling Delegate ..

  if (result != null)
  {
     //Remaining Code...  
  }
}
```

#### callBack

```
static async Task<bool> SendMessagesAsync(IAsyncCollector<Message> collector, IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions)
{
  SetProviderExemption(exemptions);
}
```

#### xUnit Test

```
[Fact]
public void MyTestA()
{
    //Arrange
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    var ringGoTransaction = RingGoExemptionTestData.GetRingGoSession();

    Mock<HttpRequest> mockHttpRequest = httpResquestFactory.CreateMockHttpRequest(ringGoTransaction);

    fixture.Customize<ProviderLocation>(c => c
        .With(x => x.ProviderId, 13)
        .With(x => x.CreatedBy, 1)
        .With(x => x.LocationReference, "222")
        .With(x => x.SiteId, 215)
        .With(x => x.IsActive, true)
    );

    var providerLocationDataMoq = fixture.Create<ProviderLocation>();
    providerExemptionServiceMoq.Setup(x => x.GetProviderLocation(13, "222")).ReturnsAsync(providerLocationDataMoq);

    var providerExemptionReceivedNotificationMoq = fixture.Create<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification>();

    fixture.Customize<RingGoMessageResponseResult>(a => a
        .With(x => x.ProviderSessionId, "1023446448745110767")
        .With(x => x.IsSuccess, true)
    );

    var ringGoMessageResponseResultMoq = fixture.Create<RingGoMessageResponseResult>();

    ringGoApiServiceMoq.Setup(x => x.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(It.IsAny<RingGoExemption>(), It.IsAny<SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(ringGoMessageResponseResultMoq)
    .Callback<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification>(providerExemptionReceivedNotificationMoq); // How to add CallBack moq which takes ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification object 

}
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can try to narrow down the exact problem? I'm sure there are some good answers out there but this question is a bit of a "wall of text" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var providerExemptionReceivedNotificationMoq = RingGoExemptionTestData.GetProviderExemptionReceivedNotification();


 ringGoApiServiceMoq.Setup(x => x.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(It.IsAny<RingGoExemption>(), It.IsAny<SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(ringGoMessageResponseResultMoq)
        .Callback((RingGoExemption exemption, SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications sendProviderExemption) => 
            {
                sendProviderExemption.Invoke(providerExemptionReceivedNotificationMoq);
            }
        );
```